# Multiple Group By Data Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I have this data

| ID | Name | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | 2020 |
| 2 | Test1 | 2021 |
| 3 | Test2 | 2020 |
| 4 | Test2 | 2020 |
| 5 | Test2 | 2021 |
| 6 | Test3 | 2020 |

My query like this

```
SELECT name, year, count(*) as count FROM table GROUPBY name, year
```

Output will be

| name | Year | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test 1 | 2020 | 1 |
| test 2 | 2020 | 2 |
| test 2 | 2021 | 1 |
| test 3 | 2020 | 1 |

How to make output like this in php or laravel

```
{
    name => test1,{
        {
            year => 2020,
            count =>  1
        },
        {
            year => 2021,
            count => 1
        }
    },
    name => test2,{
        {
            year => 2020,
            count =>  2
        },
        {
            year => 2021,
            count => 1
        }
    },
    name => test3,{
        {
            year => 2020,
            count =>  1
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: What had you tried so far? note that MySQL is not about rendering data, it's about selecting it. your data shapes/structure is what to work on with PHP.

Comment: I try to foreach data to output but some data dosent show, when I use group by year.

Comment: It's not clear what the desired output should look like. Currently it looks like badly formatted JSON with some PHP associative array elements. Can you instead share properly formatted PHP array or JSON output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the grouped results from Database you can apply `groupBy` in  `Collection` and apply the format

```
$query = DB::table('yourtable')
    ->select([
      'name',
      'year',
      DB::raw('count(*) as count'),
    ])
    ->groupBy(['name','year'])
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->map(function($yearlyCollection){
      return $yearlyCollection
            ->map(function($eachData){
              return Arr::except((array)$eachData,'name');
            });
    })
  ->map(function($value,$key){
    return [
      'name' => $key,
      'yearData' => $value->toArray(),
    ];
  })
  ->values()
  ->toArray();
```

will Produde the output like this

```
[
     [
       "name" => "Test1",
       "yearData" => [
         [
           "year" => 2020,
           "count" => 1,
         ],
         [
           "year" => 2021,
           "count" => 1,
         ],
       ],
     ],
     [
       "name" => "Test2",
       "yearData" => [
         [
           "year" => 2020,
           "count" => 2,
         ],
         [
           "year" => 2021,
           "count" => 1,
         ],
       ],
     ],
     [
       "name" => "Test3",
       "yearData" => [
         [
           "year" => 2020,
           "count" => 1,
         ],
       ],
     ],
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This Might not be perfect, but something like this should suffice:

```
Data::select("year",DB::raw("count(id) as count"))
                        ->groupBy('Name')
                        ->get();
```

Comment: Output is already good from my query, but render is not what i want